# Regular expression to match any folder path of any length on Windows and Unix

Tags: python, regex, directory, path

Is it possible to make regular expression that will match any folder path of any length on Windows and Unix?
So, for example, regex should match: `C:Users/Hp Workstation`, as well as: `C:Users/User1/Downloads` and `C:Users/Desktop/Python/python-2.7.7-docs`, and even much longer paths...
This was just example. I meant some kind of universal regex to match absolutely any path(any partition, any folder, any subfolder...)
I would like to do it in Python. 
Thanks in advance!

**ONE OF THE ANSWERS:**
This is one of the possible solutions I came to, that works for the vast majority of different paths, in most programming languages.

```
^([a-zA-Z]?\:?[^\/\\:*?"<>|]*|[\/\\]{1,2}[^\/\\:*?"<>|]+[\/\\][^\/\\:*?"<>|]+)([\/\\][^\/\\:*?"<>|]+)+
```

Comment: This will work, however if you're looking to seek, find and store filepaths, there are likely better methods to do so. https://regex101.com/r/dqaHcv/1

Comment: Thank you very much for answer and effort! But I meant some kind of universal regex to match absolutely any path(any partition, any folder, any subfolder...). This was just example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, this matches local as well as network paths.

`^(C:[\S\s]+|\\[\S\s]+)` or `^(C:.*|\\.*)`

example

```
a = 'C:Users/Hp Workstation'
b = 'C:Users/User1/Downloads'
c = 'Users/Desktop/Python/python-2.7.7-docs'
d = '\\lol.com\Dfsdd\Dfsrerere\ytererwe\9jungnjfl\Projects'
e = 'lol.com\Dfsdd\Dfsrerere\ytererwe\9jungnjfl\Projects'
lis=[a,b,c,d,e]
for item in lis:
    print(re.findall(r'^(C:[\S\s]+|\\[\S\s]+)', item ))
```

**output**

```
['C:Users/Hp Workstation']
['C:Users/User1/Downloads']
[]
['\\lol.com\\Dfsdd\\Dfsrerere\\ytererwe\\9jungnjfl\\Projects']
[]
```

Comment: It works! Maybe not in all cases, but it is definitely a good foundation for further upgrades! For different partitions you should use:```^([A-Z]:[\S\s]+|\\[\S\s]+)```. Thank you very much for answer and effort!